# Selenium : How to check whether word exist?

Tags: python, selenium

I am new in `python` `selenium`, Need help to detect word in `selenium`, example : if submit word found, then close window.

Please help

Comment: Hello, please add some code showing what you have tried so far. Then people can help you find a solution without writing the whole program themselves.

Comment: use findElements() method with xpath of //*[contains(text(), 'your_word')]  Then check returned webelement array for size>0.